# What is difference between the perception of employees and the perceptions of employees?

Tags: phrases

In some sentences, I see the use of "the perceptions of employees", but sometimes it is "the perception of employees". Whether these paraphrases have the same meaning and I can use both of them? Could you tell me the difference between them? Thanks a lot.

Comment: More context, please.  What differences do you already notice?  Please [edit] to include them in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible meanings here (lots of ambiguity):

Perceptions of Employees could mean:

1. How the employees are perceived by more than one person
2. More than one perception of employees by one or more people.
3. How more than one employee perceives one or more things.
4. How more than one employee has more than one perception of something. Example: The employees perceive the vacation policy as generous and flexible.

Perception of Employees could mean:

1. A generalization (or collective view) of how employees are perceived by more than one person
2. How one person perceives more than one employee.
3. How more than one employee perceives something
4. How more than one employee collectively perceives something.

This may not be exhaustive, but should give you an idea of the differences.

Some clearer usage examples: 
The CEO perceives employees as expendable. 
According to a survey done by Human Resources, the employees generally perceive the CEO as heartless.

Comment: Clear logic. Only the context may clarify which option applies.